# Unable to upload large csv file using ajax jquery post | Asp MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have this code which helps user to upload a csv file and put it in SQL SB using bulk upload. 
I am able to run this in local m/c and azure environment successfully when I upload a csv file of size 30 MB. No errors, runs fine.

**I get "not found" error when I try to upload a file larger than 30 MB only in azure env.** Any file size runs fine in local m/c.

I get error result at line  -  `$("#actionOP").text(err.statusText);`
before even hitting the controller. What am I doing wrong ?

cshtml code:

```
<input id="postedFile" type="file" accept=".csv" />
        <button onclick="UpClaims();">Upload as Claims Data</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function UpClaims() {
                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {

                    var fileUpload = $("#postedFile").get(0);
                    var files = fileUpload.files;
                    // Create FormData object
                    var fileData = new FormData();
                    // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                    }

                    $("#divProcessing").show();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("UploadClaimsFile", "Home")',
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                        processData: false, // Not to process data
                        data: fileData,
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#divProcessing").hide();
                            $("#actionOP").text(result);
                            $('#postedFile').val("");
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            $("#divProcessing").hide();
                            $("#actionOP").text(err.statusText);
                            $('#postedFile').val("");
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            alert("FormData is not supported.");
        }
    }
        </script>
```

Web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="99999" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647"/>
<security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach used is to break a large file up into small chunks. Bellow article about this solution

[Upload large files to MVC / WebAPI using partitioning](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034347/Upload-large-files-to-MVC-WebAPI-using-partitionin)

> The approach used is to break a large file up into small chunks,
>   upload them, then merge them back together on the server - file
>   transfer by partitioning. The article shows sending files to an MVC
>   server from both a webpage using JavaScript and a Web-form
>   httpclient, and can be implemented using either MVC or WebAPI.